# Spring Boot Elastic Beanstalk java.time.DateTimeException when running java -jar

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have a Spring Boot multi-module project deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with CodePipeline.

My Procfile:
`web: java -jar parent/module1/target/y-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

My Buildfile:
`build: cd parent && mvn package`

The output I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0
        at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidValue(ValueRange.java:311)
        at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:703)
        at java.time.LocalDate.of(LocalDate.java:267)
        at java.time.LocalDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.java:336)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader.decodeMsDosFormatDateTime(CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader.getTime(CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntry.<init>(JarEntry.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.access$400(JarFileEntries.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.next(JarFileEntries.java:366)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.next(JarFileEntries.java:350)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile$2.nextElement(JarFile.java:204)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile$2.nextElement(JarFile.java:195)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.next(JarFileArchive.java:189)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.next(JarFileArchive.java:174)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

I went to manually execute the `java -jar` command on my EC2 instance and it yields the same error.

I haven't found a lot when looking for an explanation, but I think it might be from the java version.

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

EC2 OS:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Edit: I've also found this - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something is wrong with your JAR file:
The `CentralDirectoryFileHeader` is reading the (ZIP compressed) JAR file and encounters an incorrect date stamp.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java

Edit: According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19518 this happens when the system where the JAR is created has a system time of 1970.

As of today (January 2020) the bugfix is not released yet.
To solve the problem you have to create a new JAR after setting the system time correctly.

Comment: Thank you but I am not very familiar with this. Can you please elaborate a little? The execution fails instantly.

Comment: Looks like you found the correct issue for this problem. I have updated my answer above.

Comment: Thank you. I gave up on Elastic Beanstalk and created a regular EC2 instance with ubuntu and installed another version of jdk to fix this.